# Grafana - How to consolidate Metrics from InfluxDB and CollectD

Tags: influxdb, grafana, collectd

we've been setting up CollectD with InfluxDB to collect metrics. The problem is to consolidate e.G. Metrics from cpu1, cpu2 and cpu3. In collectd (at least version 5.2) it is possible to enable the 'aggregate' plugin to exactly do what i need to. But we're using Debian 7 and surprise - collectd is only available in version 5.1.

Do you guys know how e.G. write a regex in grafana like this, so that i dont need to specify each metric for each cpu (it is not working below):

> SELECT mean("value") FROM ".cpu-**{0-3}**.cpu-idle" WHERE
>   $timeFilter GROUP BY time($interval) fill(null)

Thank you very much!

EDIT:
I actually find out that iam able to specify multiple data sources ...FROM ".cpu-**1**.cpu-idle", ".cpu-**2**.cpu-idle" ... that results in one data line per source (which is obviously way too much).

Comment: I'd suggest using the collectd apt repo instead of the debian packages.

https://collectd.org/download.shtml#debian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@AussieDan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3485927/aussiedan). It's actually kind a embarrassing that i haven't even take a look on their website. I only visited the debian.org website.

The Answer solves my Problem on the most perfect way.